# Add leading 0's to value until length is 8 characters long

Tags: python, recursion, binary

For homework, we are asked to create a function that takes a binary input, increments the value by 1, and then displays the binary value of the new number. The output value must be an 8-bit string (8 characters long).

The following code returns the correct value, but I do not know how to add the leading zeros to the value.

```
def numToBinary(n):
    if n == 0:
        return ''
    elif isOdd(n):
        return numToBinary(n // 2) + '1'
    else:
        return numToBinary(n // 2) + '0'

def binaryToNum(s):
    if s == '':
        return 0
    elif int(s[0]) == 0:
        return 0 + binaryToNum(s[1:])
    elif int(s[0]) == 1:
        return 2**(len(s) - 1) + binaryToNum(s[1:])

def increment(s):
    binToNum = binaryToNum(s) + 1
    numToBin = numToBinary(binToNum)
    return numToBin
```

A hint given to solve this problem was: **"Consider how could you use the
function len() and string multiplication with * to make sure that the output has enough leading zeros?"**

Could someone please point me in the right direction? Thank you!

***Note:*** An example output should be:

```
>>> increment('00000001')
'00000010'
```

Comment: `string.zfill(8)` will put enough zeros at the beginning of `string` to make it 8 characters long.

Comment: @zondo Post it as an answer

Comment: @Barmar: Okay. Done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calculate how many zeroes you will need. Then prepend them to `value`.

```
value = '01'
needed = 8 - len(value)
value = '0' * needed + value
```

You can also use `zfill()`:

```
value = value.zfill(8)
```

Comment: "just use zfill."